# Why would a react-native alert component render twice when the visibility state was not changed?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an alert component that renders twice as soon as I add code to componentWillMount in the main component. [The project is an expo project](https://expo.io/)

I've worked around it by setting the property controlling the visibility of the alert component to false and then calling this.startAlert() which changes the visibility state within the componentWillMount procedure. Before the workaround the visibility state was only changed after pressing a button on the dialog.

This works. It shows the alert dialog once. this.startAlert() ; is executed in the promise.

```
componentWillMount() {

    const  setPosition = (pos) => {

        console.log(pos) ;

    // We need the "latitude" and the "longitude"
    // in order to lookup the "address" from the
    // Google maps API.
    const {
      coords: {
        latitude,
        longitude,
      },
    } = pos;

    // Fetches data from the Google Maps API then sets
    // the "address" state based on the response.
    fetch(`${URL}${latitude},${longitude}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json(), e => console.error(e))
      .then(({
        results: [
          { formatted_address },
        ],
      }) => {
            this.setAddress( formatted_address ) ;
            this.startAlert() ;         
      });
    } ;


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition) ;

}
```

Whereas this fails. The alert component is shown twice. this.startAlert() ; is called outside of the fetch promise.

```
componentWillMount() {

    const  setPosition = (pos) => {

        console.log(pos) ;

    // We need the "latitude" and the "longitude"
    // in order to lookup the "address" from the
    // Google maps API.
    const {
      coords: {
        latitude,
        longitude,
      },
    } = pos;

    // Fetches data from the Google Maps API then sets
    // the "address" state based on the response.
    fetch(`${URL}${latitude},${longitude}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json(), e => console.error(e))
      .then(({
        results: [
          { formatted_address },
        ],
      }) => {
            this.setAddress( formatted_address ) ;      
      });
    } ;

    this.startAlert() ; 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition) ;

}
```

Why would a react-native alert component render twice when the visibility state was not changed ?

Edit: Code that sets the address.

```
// Getter for "Immutable.js" state data...
get data() {
  return this.state.data;
}

// Setter for "Immutable.js" state data...
set data(data) {
  this.setState({ data });
}

setAddress = (address) => {
    this.data = this.data.set('address', address ) ;
}
```

Comment: what does `this.setAddress` do exactly? Does it update the state?

Comment: why do you have two setPosition functions?

Comment: this.setAddress does update the state. It sets an address.

Comment: why do you have two setPosition functions?  ... an editing error on my part. Sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be helpful to highlight the particular differences between the two code snippets since at first glance and even a little bit of a reading they look mostly the same. The definition of `this.setAddress(...)` seems not to be included but does it transitively call `this.setState(...)`? `this.setState(...)` causes a re-render of `this`.